# Unable to convert string to human-readable format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format, parseexception

What is wrong with my code here? I'm unable return a String in the format I'd like...

**Method Call:**

```
incident.setTargetDate(DateUtil.formatResolutionTime(targetDateList.get(i)));
```

**Formatter:**

```
public class DateUtil {

    public static String formatResolutionTime(String startDateString) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date startDate = null;

        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
        return newDateString;    
    }        
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-05-26T00:00:00+02:00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
    at app.util.DateUtil.formatResolutionTime(DateUtil.java:19)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.retrieveTicketsForTable(TableViewController.java:194)
    at app.controller.TableViewController.initialize(TableViewController.java:139)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at app.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You have to define two DateFormatter, one for Input (parse) and one for Output(Format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two formats. One for parsing the input format and one for formating the Output.

```
public static String formatResolutionTime(String startDateString) {
    DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"); //Format for parsing the Input string
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); //Format for formatting the output
    Date startDate = null;

    try {
        startDate = dfParse.parse(startDateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String newDateString = df.format(startDate);
    System.out.println(newDateString);
    return newDateString;

}
```

Comment: Could you add the explanation on top of the solution? I'll give oyu a +1 since you beat me to the clock :p

Comment: Probably because you gave a functiionnal code but didn't explain what was his problem or why he had it.

Comment: If you look at the date format in the exception, i.e. ``2017-05-26T00:00:00+02:00`` the code above works if you drop ``ZZZZ`` from the formatter. So the line looks like ``DateFormat dfParse = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");``

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the exception `Unparseable date: "2017-05-26T00:00:00+02:00"`, because you are trying to parse a String of the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX"` , but telling the formatter that your string is of type `MM/dd/yyyy.`
Your input String is of the format `"2017-05-26T00:00:00+02:00"` and you want the output in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so as suggested in other posts, you need two formatters.

```
public static String formatResolutionTime(String startDateString) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX");
        Date startDate = null;

        try {
            startDate = df.parse(startDateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DateFormat newFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        String newDateString = newFormatter.format(startDate);
        System.out.println(newDateString);
        return newDateString;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're checking for a date in the format MM/DD/YYYY but provides a date with format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: @GhostCat Could you just point me to the question where I put the comment? I don't really remember what I said. If I remember correctly, you closed a question where there was a NPE caused by a typo -- which is logical. I don't blame you for that, as the question had no purpose. Saying you love to close NPE questions with the link to "How do I fix NPE" isn't a blame.

Comment: The OP deleted his question; so I cant point you there any more ;-) You said / asked if I hate NPE questions because I am closing them "all the time" or something like that.

Comment: Btw: not the greatest answer, but showing my appreciation for your focus on understanding how this community works ;-)  ... at least that is how I see it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use two DateFormat objects: one for parsing (input -> date) and one for formatting (date -> output).

Your input is `2017-05-26T00:00:00+02:00`. Let's break it down (refer [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)):

- `2017`: the year in the format `yyyy`
- `05`: the month in the format `MM`
- `26`: the day in the format `dd`
- `T`: separator between date and time in the format of character `'T'`
- `00`: the hour in the format `HH` (**not** `hh`)
- `00`: the minutes in the format `mm`
- `00`: the seconds in the format `ss`
- `+02:00`: the time zone in the format `XXX`

So your SimpleDateFormat parser pattern will be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:XXX
```

**Additional notes**

In case of ParseException your code could result in unexpected behaviour, in fact after the try/catch block your `startDate` will be null and the formatter will try to format the null date and return the result, generating a `NullPointerException`.

Said that, my code would be:

```
private static final String PARSE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX";
private static final String FORMAT_PATTERN = "MM/dd/yyyy";
// we cannot declare the SimpleDateFormat as static since it isn't thread-safe

public static String formatResolutionTime(String startDateString) {

    try {
        DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(PARSE_PATTERN);
        Date startDate = parser.parse(startDateString);

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT_PATTERN);
        return formatter.format(startDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error"; // or whatever, but return a string here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread of answers would not be complete without the modern answer.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String newDateString = OffsetDateTime.parse(startDateString).format(dtf);
```

The result is

```
05/26/2017
```

The answers I have read until now are correct — and outdated. In 2017 it’s time to skip the old classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`, and use [the newer Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), in this case `DateTimeFormatter` and `OffsetDateTime`. This is even more appropriate as your original date-time string conforms with ISO 8601, the format that the newer classes “understand” as their default. So we need not give an explicit format for parsing (as would be needed with `SimpleDateFormat`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    //System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    return dateFormat.format(date);
```

It works for me)